# bash - regex string from command line

Tags: bash, ssh, wget, cat

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/myfolder/myfile | ssh mypc 'cat > /tmp/myfile'
```

Note that 'myfile' is the name used in wget and cat commands. So, my question is if I can apply a regex to the http://example.com/myfolder/myfile in order to pass it to cat command removing all except for the name of the file (in this case m file). Long story short, I would like to have ONE input to give to both commands with help of regex for the second one, something like:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/myfolder/myfile | ssh mypc 'cat > /tmp/regex(http://example.com/myfolder/myfile, last_occurrence_of(/))'
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `basename` command:

```
 url=http://example.com/myfolder/myfile; wget -O - $url | ssh mypc "cat > /tmp/$(basename $url)"
```

You can also use the bash operator `##`:

```
 url=http://example.com/myfolder/myfile; wget -O - $url | ssh mypc "cat > /tmp/${url##*/}"
```

In this case the regex is `*/`.

Comment: i really appreciate your help, didn't know about that command.